# Problems with reshaping data using pivot.table in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

I have dataframe laid out like below, with multiple different drillholes/[DH] that pass through a single underground structure, with a [VARIABLE] and [DISTANCE_TO] the structure itself, with 0 being distance within the structure. The variables are floats, changed to X here for simplicity's sake.

```
[DH]    [VARIABLE]  [DISTANCE_TO]
DH111   X           3
DH111   X           2
DH111   X           1
DH111   X           0
DH111   X           1
DH111   X           2
DH111   X           4
DH222   X           3
DH222   X           2
DH222   X           1
DH222   X           0
DH222   X           0
DH222   X           1
DH222   X           2
DH333   X           2
DH333   X           1
DH333   X           0
DH333   X           1
DH333   X           2
```

I'm trying to use pandas pivot function to alter the data so I have one column for DISTANCE_TO with VARIABLE for each DHID, like this:

```
[DISTANCE_TO]     [DH111 VAR]       [DH222 VAR]     [DH333 VAR]
4                 NaN               X               NaN
3                 X                 X               NaN
2                 X                 X               X
1                 X                 X               X
0                 X                 X               X
0                 NaN               X               NaN
1                 X                 X               X
2                 X                 X               X
3                 X                 NaN             NaN
4                 NaN               NaN             NaN
```

This is the code I'm using `df_split = pd.pivot_table(df,index=[‘DHID', 'DISTANCE_TO])` but I'm not getting the DHID split up as I'd like, it's just re-arranging [DISTANCE_TO] into ascending numeric order... One reason this might not work is because there are certain DHID that pass through the structure for longer, example in DH222 there are two rows where 0 is a value, I'm not sure how this will interfere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify columns and values as well in [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html).

You’re right that there is the issue of how to select for several values the first one. That’s the role of the `aggfunc` parameter of `pivot_table`. By default, it’s `np.mean`, which only works for numeric types. If your variable are strings such as `'X'`, you can for example select the first one with `'first'`:

```
>>> df.pivot_table(columns='[DH]', index='[DISTANCE_TO]', values='[VARIABLE]', aggfunc='first')
[DH]          DH111 DH222 DH333
[DISTANCE_TO]                  
0                 X     X     X
1                 X     X     X
2                 X     X     X
3                 X     X   NaN
4                 X   NaN   NaN
```

You can also write your own `aggfunc`, it’s basically a function that receives a `pd.Series` of values from the `[VARIABLE]` column, and it needs to return a single scalar value. So to do the same as `first` with a lambda you could do:

```
>>> df.pivot_table(columns='[DH]', index='[DISTANCE_TO]', values='[VARIABLE]', aggfunc=lambda s: s.iloc[0])
[DH]          DH111 DH222 DH333
[DISTANCE_TO]                  
0                 X     X     X
1                 X     X     X
2                 X     X     X
3                 X     X   NaN
4                 X   NaN   NaN
```